# Where and when should data be inserted into a database in the arrange phase in xunit framework?

Tags: asp.net, xunit, arrange-act-assert

Where and when should data be inserted into a database in the arrange phase in xunit framework?

By the arrange phase I mean the Arrange from the Arrange, Act, Assert pattern.

To prepare data for each test method I am using a separate class. E.g.:

```
class CasesRelationTypeTest
{
        [Theory]
        [MemberData(nameof(CasesRelationTypeTestData.DeleteAsyncTest), MemberType = typeof(CasesRelationTypeTestData))]
        public void DeleteAsyncTest(CasesRelationTypeDto data)
        {
            //...
        }

       //...
}

class CasesRelationTypeTestData
{
    public TheoryData<CasesRelationTypeDto> DeleteAsyncTest { get; private set; }

    public CasesRelationTypeTestData()
    {
        InitDeleteAsync();
    }

    private void InitDeleteAsync()
    {
        //should I insert the data here? but then it will be inserted for all the tests in the CasesRelationTypeTest, which is not what I want
        DeleteAsyncTest.Add(new CasesRelationTypeDto
        {
            //...
        });
    }
}
```

I am okay with changing the way in which data is provided to a theory if you propose something different (which would allow for a well devised arrange phase).